# effective search with multi key map

Tags: c++, search, dictionary

I have a map with key as struct. Struct (key) contain two strings x and y.

And two keys can have same values for x but they would certainly differ for y.

I am curious for best search for value using these two keys.

Comment: Use code to explain yourself.

Comment: Adding to above ... map with struct (mentioned above) as key and value another struct. Can I get insert/remove/search close to O(1) in this.

Comment: You can use hashing algorithm to get a unique key for map

Comment: A `std::map` is implemented as a balanced binary tree and will never be O(1), but is relatively rarely problematically slow.  It maintains a sorted order - which is evident when iterating - so if you care what order you iterate elements in - or are just as happy for it to be by `y` primarily then by `x` - consider comparing `y` first if it's more likely to differ.  If you don't need an order, `std::unordered_map` may be an option - you can find a `hash_combine` function to combine hashes of the individual strings.  Plenty of examples of how to do all that on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: Further tip - if you use `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` as keys instead of your own `struct`, then `std::map` will know how to compare them already (with `.first` being the primary key and `.second` secondary).

Comment: How would you search in this using any key...

Answer (score 0):

The [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) should contain each key value only once.  This is why it can provide operator `[]` to uniquely address a perticular key.

If you have several values for the same key, you should use [multimaps](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/) instead. With multimaps, you'd have to use `find()` to access to the values.

You can experiment with this small and very basic example:

```
std::map<char, int> mymap;              // unique key 
std::multimap<char, int> mymulti;       // non-unique key 

mymap.insert(std::pair<char, int>('a', 10));        
mymap.insert(std::pair<char, int>('b', 15));
mymap.insert(std::pair<char, int>('b', 20));    // problem: will not be inserted !  
mymulti.insert(std::pair<char, int>('a', 10));
mymulti.insert(std::pair<char, int>('b', 15));
mymulti.insert(std::pair<char, int>('b', 20));  // no problem
mymulti.insert(std::pair<char, int>('c', 25));
std::cout << "First:\n";             // b is there only once
for (auto x : mymap) std::cout << x.first << ":" << x.second << "\n";
std::cout << "\nSecond:\n";           // b is ther twice
for (auto x : mymulti) std::cout << x.first << ":" << x.second << "\n";

std::cout << "first[b]=" << mymap['b'] << std::endl;    // map access (direct)
std::cout << "Second[b]={";                             // multimap access  (iterator)
for (auto x = mymulti.find('b'); x != mymulti.end() && x->first == 'b'; x++) std::cout << x->second << " ";
std::cout << "}\n";
```

Both maps and multimaps are generally implemented as a binary search tree. So it'll be efficient for search.

Comment: Sorry for confusion.... I can use map since pair<x, y> which I am using as a key will surely be unique as y is unique. Question is how can I insert/remove/search in an efficient manner in this using these two keys.